# How to make a slider with infinite and smooth scrolling without delay?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a logo slider where I need to implement infinite smooth scrolling without delay. Now there is a smooth scrolling, but there is still a delay and the slider stops. How can this be resolved?
An example of how it should be (slider with logos): https://www.seven-formation.com/

```js
const logosSlider = new Swiper(".testimonials__logos", {
  loop: true,
  freeMode: true,
  freeModeMomentum: false,
  speed: 3000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 0,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (them missing HTML) to make a minimal reproducible example. At this state, your question will get closed.